# Saving a list of numbers in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, integer

I'm making a program to book out equipment from a studio. I'm saving everything to XML (I will eventually have it synchronising online), and I can save everything except an ArrayList of Integers. These Integers are of the unique ID of the Equipment that is being used.

My question, how can I store and retrieve them in the XML? I am fine with saving them but it's the reading of them that i'm having trouble with, this is an excerpt of saving the equipment:

```
for(Integer i : b.getEquipment()){ 
                Element equipmentID = doc.createElement("EquipmentID");
                equipmentID.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(i.toString()));
                theEquipment.appendChild(equipmentID);

            }
```

And in the XML, this looks like.. (From < Equipment >)

```
<Booking>
<Person>1</Person>
<Project>Current</Project>
<Equipment>
    <EquipmentID>2</EquipmentID>
</Equipment>
<DateOut>09/09 11:24:15</DateOut>
</Booking>
```

My trouble now, is how do I read in the < EquipmentID > tags?
There could be lots of < EquipmentID > tags as lot's of Equipment could be booked out.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question... what exactly is the problem with reading the tags? What are you using to parse this?

Comment: Agree -- this question seems terribly incomplete.

Comment: where is your code that is reading any of the XML?

Answer (score 1):

If `Booking` node contains a list of `Equipment ID`'s, and you need to keep these ID's without additional info for every Equipment ID, then convert list of your equipment id's to a comma delimited string. Like that: `<EquipmentIDS>1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7</EquipmentIDS>`

And upon parsing employ `StringTokenizer` to extract every equipment id from this string.

Comment: Not that this wouldn't work, but the senior software architects at my job would kill you if you actually did something like this in production code...

Comment: If there are *only* equipment id's and no more associated with these ids info, why don't pass them as a string? I think your senior architect does not have experience with high load projects. Extra tags in this case will produce unecessary load on communication channels and won't be useful at all.

Comment: It is a data separation issue - It breaks conventions and expectance and relies on everyone ever having to work with this format to know that this is intended to be a list. For "high load projects" (which I assure you we have plenty of experience with), one shouldn't use XML as a communication protocol anyways if performance is an issue - ASN.1 or other binary formats would be superior.

Comment: MQ solutions I worked on, IBM Websphere MQ for instance, use xml as message format. And there are thousands of messages every minute. No binary formats are involved. Once again, if there is only list of ids, and I do not need to associate additional info for every id, I would select a list and pass it as a body of one tag. If there is a `special` consideration, then it may be a different solution. But this question did not mention it.

Comment: Of course OPs problem is trivial anyways so it wouldn't matter if he chose your solution or added each ID as its own element. But another problem with your approach is you can't create an XSD schema element for that comma-separated list (as a list and not a simple element) which means you can't automate parsing with JAXB or similar tools, or do automated XSLT translations and the like. The thing is that it breaks convention - a list of elements should be represented as a list of nodes, and not as some homebrewn non-standard format.